# Custom Layer of Validation base in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

**Edited**
In a project I'm working, exists three layes: Business, DataAccess and DataTransferObjects. In the business layer I need to build a validation mechanism and I want to use `DataAnnotation`.

In an Asp.net MVC standard application, the `Controller` class is responsible to validate, and you can access and edit the validation by `ModelState` property.

I need to validate a DataTransferObject that is marked with `DataAnnotation`without using a `Controller` class. Instead I need to use my custom class in business layer for that.

So far I understood tha all DataAnnotations, focused in validation, inherits from `ValidationAttribute`. How can I validate a class dynamically and put the error messages in a `Dictionary<string,string>`? (Like `Controller.ModelState` validate the model and build a Dictionary of errors messages).

Comment: What's wrong with just using the DataAnnotations provided by ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I'm using `DataAnnotations`, but I can't use Controller class. It seems that my question is not very clear. So I edited the question to make myself more clear. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public static class MyValidatorExtensions
{
    public static bool Validate(this object obj, out List<ValidationResult> results)
    {
        ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(obj, null, null);
        results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        return Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, results, true);
    }
}
```

Now you can call this as an extension method on every object.

```
var validationErrors = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool valid = new Person().Validate(out validationErrors);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description of the application, it appears to be a fairly standard one and you shouldn't have any problem using DataAnnotations the way they are intended. I will make some assumptions here about how the application is structured (to fill in missing detail) and will explain how I think you can use DataAnnotations for your business validation.

I assume that the Business layer consists of an object model that reflects your application domain. Each object in the the domain model exposes attributes and potentially methods that implement business rules. This is the application layer in which you want to code your validation, and indeed it is the appropriate place for domain validation rules.

I'm assuming you are using Entity Framework or a similar ORM for your Data Access layer.

Your MVC controllers do not access the domain model directly. Instead ViewModels (you call them Data Transfer Objects) are used to structure data appropriately for individual Views. The ViewModels thus contain data abstracted from the domain model, to which domain validation rules apply.

Now, this is all fine, and as intended. You could add other DataAnnotations to properties in your ViewModel if you wish to override domain validation rules for particular views, but it is not required. However, while client-side validation will be executed by MVC for view model properties, it will not be for the underlying domain objects.

So, using the `ModelState.IsValid` method will not work in this case. To perform validation on the domain model, you can trap the `DbEntityValidationException` after attempting to save the object:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, BlogView view)
{
    try
    {
        Blog blog = Mapper.Map(view);      //map view model to domain object using eg. Automapper
        db.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        var error = ex.EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors.First();
        this.ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to rely on the exception thrown by EntityFramework, you can explicitly trigger validation using the `DbContext.GetValidationErrors()` method:

```
foreach (var validationResults in db.GetValidationErrors())
{
    foreach (var error in validationResults.ValidationErrors)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Entity Property: {0}, Error {1}",
                          error.PropertyName,error.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, your domain objects can implement the `IValidatableObject` interface, and use its Validate() method:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (Title == BloggerName)
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult
         ("Blog Title cannot match Blogger Name", new[] { "Title", “BloggerName” });
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/gg193959.aspx for futher details.

Comment: It's a good approach, however I'm not using entity framework, in fact I'm not using any ORM at all.